# linux kernel dts sgpio_out parameter meaning

Tags: linux-kernel, gpio, device-tree

This is one sample in [DTS file](https://github.com/openbmc/linux/blob/fc8d4fdba5bd2b9b1cea2aa8a731531943c45aa7/arch/arm/boot/dts/microchip/lan966x-pcb8291.dts#L32)

```dts
    led-s0-green {
        label = "s0:green";
        gpios = <&sgpio_out 2 1 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        default-state = "off";
    };

    led-s1-blue {
        label = "s1:blue";
        gpios = <&sgpio_out 3 0 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        default-state = "off";
    };

    led-s1-green {
        label = "s1:green";
        gpios = <&sgpio_out 3 1 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        default-state = "off";
    };
```

Can anyone tell me what the 2 and 0 in `<&sgpio_out 2 0 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>` mean? I can't find any information.

I've searched the site and there are no relevant documents.

Comment: "*I can't find any information.*" - Where did you look, and what did you look for? The data format of a property is supposed to be documented in a bindings document in **Documentation/devicetree/bindings/** in kernel source. As written in **gpio/gpio.txt**: "*The exact meaning of each specifier cell is controller specific, and must be documented in the device tree binding for the device*".

Comment: But I'm not sure what the difference is between the gpio and sgpio_out parameters. I looked in the linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me what the 2 and 0 in `<&sgpio_out 2 0 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>` mean?

The data format of a property is supposed to be documented in a bindings document in **Documentation/devicetree/bindings/** in kernel source. As written in [gpio/gpio.txt](https://github.com/openbmc/linux/blob/fc8d4fdba5bd2b9b1cea2aa8a731531943c45aa7/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt#L37):

```
The exact meaning of each specifier cell is controller specific, and must be documented 
in the device tree binding for the device.
```

---

In this case the "device" is a gpio controller that is referred to with the label `sgpio_out`. That node label is defined in the included file [lan966x.dtsi](https://github.com/openbmc/linux/blob/fc8d4fdba5bd2b9b1cea2aa8a731531943c45aa7/arch/arm/boot/dts/microchip/lan966x.dtsi#L580):

```dts
        sgpio: gpio@e2004190 {
            compatible = "microchip,sparx5-sgpio";
            ...
            sgpio_out: gpio@1 {
                compatible = "microchip,sparx5-sgpio-bank";
                reg = <1>;
                gpio-controller;
                #gpio-cells = <3>;
            };
            ...
        };
```

The binding document for this device (identified by its `compatible` property) is apparently [Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/microchip,sparx5-sgpio.yaml](https://github.com/openbmc/linux/blob/fc8d4fdba5bd2b9b1cea2aa8a731531943c45aa7/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/microchip%2Csparx5-sgpio.yaml#L93), and seems to contain the answer to your question:

```
Note that the SGIO pin is defined by *2* numbers, 
a port number between 0 and 31,
and a bit index, 0 to 3.
```

If the meanings of "port number" and/or "bit index" are unclear, then refer to the hardware datasheet regarding how this device operates. and its connections